# ref.watch not watching over state change of a Provider function

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, riverpod-generator

I am using a Consumer to watch over state changes in an Object provided by Provider function but the ref.watch doesn't seem to rebuild the Consumer.

Application contains 2 pages: `home_page` and `settings_page`.

Providers: `dbHelperInstanceProvider`, `sharedPreferencesProvider`, `maalaCompletedProvider` provider functions for providing instances of classes `DBHelper`, `SPHelper` classes and other simple and necessary functionalities. 
Major Providers being: **`currentMaalaManagerProvider`** and **`CurrentStateProvider`** providing instance of **CurrentMaalaManager** class to be as repository instance inside riverpod class **CurrentStateProvider**, which is used for showing data on home_page and triggering functions for changing states.
Below is the code I feel important to share to understand situation better:

CurrentMaalaManagerProvider function:

```
@riverpod
CurrentMaalaManager currentMaalaManager(CurrentMaalaManagerRef ref) {
  var db = ref.watch(dbHelperInstanceProvider);
  var sp = ref.watch(sharedPreferencesProvider);
  var compl = ref.watch(maalaCompletedProvider);
  return CurrentMaalaManager(db, sp, compl);
}
```

CurrentMaalaManager class:

```
class CurrentMaalaManager {
  final DBHelper _db;
  final SPHelper _sp;
  final MaalaCompleted completionStatus;
  int? _nextMaalaLengthOnRestart; // ATTRIBUTE WHOSE CHANGING VALUES ref.watch IS FAILING TO REACT TO 
  int? get nextMaalaLengthOnRestart => _nextMaalaLengthOnRestart;
  int? _lastClearedJaaps;
  CurrentMaalaManager(this._db, this._sp, this.completionStatus) {
    init();
  }
  void init() async {
    _nextMaalaLengthOnRestart = await _sp.getNextMaalaLengthOnRestart();
  }

 Future<CurrentMaalaData> setMaalaLength(
      int newLength,
      Future<bool?> Function() fromNextMaala,
      CurrentMaalaData currentMaalaObject) async {
    //...
    bool? fromNext = await fromNextMaala();
    if(fromNext==true){
       await _sp.setNextMaalaLengthOnRestart(newLength);
      _nextMaalaLengthOnRestart = newLength;
    }
    //...
   //returning CurrentMaalaData object for setting new state in CurrentStateProvider-> which will be used to trigger this function.
  }

 //...other functions (which also change value of member '_nextMaalaLengthOnRestart' ) here containing majority of other logic
}
```

CurrentStateProvider class:

```
@riverpod
class CurrentStateProvider extends _$CurrentStateProvider {
  @override
  FutureOr<CurrentMaalaData> build() async {
    var repo = ref.watch(currentMaalaManagerProvider);
    return await repo.loadLastSavedData();
  }
   Future<void> setMaalaLength(
      int newLength, Future<bool?> Function() fromNextMaala) async {
    var repo = ref.read(currentMaalaManagerProvider);

    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async => await repo.setMaalaLength(
        newLength, fromNextMaala, state.requireValue));
  }
  // ... other similar functions using currentMaalaManagerProvider as repo to make changes and setting new states.

}
```

A Consumer Widget inside **home_page** watching over providers:

```
Consumer(
            builder: (context, ref, child) {

              var display = ref.watch(currentStateProviderProvider);
              var completed = ref.watch(maalaCompletedProvider);

              return display.when(
                data: (data) {
                //...using data from watching over providers.
                  return Column(...);
                },
                error: (error, stackTrace) => Center(
                    child: Text("Error:\n $error\nStackTrace:\n$stackTrace")),
                loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
          }
        )
      // An onTap function changing state:
     //onTap: () =>
    //       ref.read(currentStateProviderProvider.notifier).increment(),
```

A Consumer inside **settings_page**:

```
Consumer(
            builder: (context, ref, child) {
             // to get current state's maalaLength attribute
              var data = ref.watch(currentStateProviderProvider.select(
                  (value) => value.whenData((value) => value.maalaLength)));
            // to get CurrentMaalaManager instance's 'nextMaalaLengthOnRestart' attribute which is only managed inside class
            // and is not a part of state provided by above provider, whose value is being stored in data variable 
              var nextLen = ref.watch(currentMaalaManagerProvider
                  .select((value) => value.nextMaalaLengthOnRestart)); // SHOULD HAVE IDEALLY WATCHED OVER CHANGES BEING TRIGGERED ON BUTTON CLICK BELOW (according to me)
           
           return data.when(
                     data: (data){
                        return //..UI...
                            ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () async {
                               int newLen =
                                int.parse(lengthInputController.text);
                               // THE CALL TO .setMaalaLength BELOW CHNAGES THE VALUE OF attb _nextMaalaLengthOnRestart in CurrentMaalaManager class
                               // whose provider is also being watched above inside Consumer
                                    await ref
                                        .read(currentStateProviderProvider.notifier)
                                        .setMaalaLength(newLen, ()=> changeLengthFromCurrentOrNextMaala(context) // a dialog function asking for yes/no and providing Future<bool?> to function as parameter.
                                );
                               })
                              },
                              child: const Text("Set"),
                            ),

                     //....
                    nextLen!=null ? Text("$nextLen") : const SizedBox(height:5) // PROBLEM DISPLAYING THIS TEXT, EXPECTEDLY RIGHT WHEN NEW VALUE IS SET
```

Now the problem is that when the button right above is clicked, it runs the function `.setMaalaLength` which is also working fine but the Consumer is not reacting to the change in state of object of class CurrentMaalaManager whose attribute *_nextMaalaLengthOnRestart* is being changed by the triggered function which in turn according to me should have changed the value being returned by the concerned provider function leading to Consumer rebuild right when I press button to change values.
Instead what's happening is when I press the back button and go back to home_page, the concerned Consumer rebuilds and when i revisit the settings_page again, the `Text("$nextLen")` is visible which I expected to be getting visible right when the button was pressed.
I don't understand this strange behavior and have also tried making all the providers non-disposible by `@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)` annotation.
In my limited knowledge and experience with riverpod, I am unable to understand the cause of this problem and to fix my code. Kindly help me with the right approaches and reasons. Thank You

Comment: It is troublesome that your currentMaalaManagerProvider is not async, but it actually cannot be "born ready" because of the async init() function in your manager.  Please return a Future from your function, awaiting the completion of init().

Comment: @RandalSchwartz You are right that it should wait for init() to execute before moving further but it seems to still work fine internally. Also, I have made it wait on your suggestion but still it does not work and same problem still persists.